# Does functional programming's deep stacks prevent garbage collection in the JVM?

Tags: scala, jvm

Suppose I allocation some large object (e.g. a vector of size N, which might be very large) and perform a sequence of m operations on it:

```
fm( .. f3( f2( f1( vec ) ) ) )
```

with each returning a collection of size N.

For simplicity let's assume each f is quite simple

```
def f5(vec: Vector[Int]) = { gc(); f6(  vec.map(_+1) ) }
```

So, vec no longer has future references at the point where each subsequent call is made. (f1's vec parameter is never used after f2 is entered, and so forth for each call)

However, because most JVMs don't decrement references until the stack unwinds (AFAIK), isn't my program *required* to consume NxM memory. By comparison in the following style only 2xM is required (and less in other implementations)

```
  var vec:Vector[Int] = ...

  for ( f <- F ) {
    vec = f(vec)
    gc()
  }
```

Does the same issue exist for tail recursive methods?

This isn't just an academic exercise - in some types of big-data type problems, we might to choose N so that our program is fits fully into RAM. In this case, should I be concerned that one style of pipelining is preferable to another?

Comment: Why not use `view` if you want to save memory?

Comment: @VictorMoroz or even better, replace the vector with an iterator. But that's not what the question is about. Do long lived stack references prevent GC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your question contains a serious misconception, and an example of disastrously bad coding.

> However, because most JVMs don't decrement references until the stack unwinds (AFAIK) ...

Actually there are no mainstream JVMs that use reference counting on references *at all*.  Instead, they all use mark-sweep, copying or generational collection algorithms of some kind that do not rely on reference counting.

Next this:

```
   def f5(vec: Vector[Int]) = { gc(); f6(  vec.map(_+1) ) }
```

I think you are trying to "force" a garbage collection with the `gc()` call.  Don't do this: it is horribly inefficient.  And even if you are only doing to investigate memory management behavior, you are most likely distorting that behavior to the extent that what you are seeing is NOT representative of normal Scala code.

Having said that, the answer is basically yes.  If your Scala function cannot be tail-call optimized, then there is the potential for a deep recursion to cause garbage retention problems.  The only "get out" would be if the JIT compiler was able to tell the GC that certain variables were "dead" at particular points in a method call.  I don't know if HotSpot JITs / GCs can do that.

(I guess, another way to do that would be for the Scala compiler to explicitly assign `null` to dead reference variables.  But that has potential performance issues when you don't have a garbage retention problem!)

Answer (score 2):

To add to @StephenC's answer

> I don't know if HotSpot JITs / GCs can do that.

The hotspot jit can do liveness analysis within a method and deem local variables as unreachable even while a frame is still on the stack. This is why JDK9 introduces [Reference.reachabilityFence](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#reachabilityFence-java.lang.Object-), under some conditions even `this` can become unreachable while executing a member method of that instance.

But that optimization only applies when there really nothing in the control flow that can still read that local variable, e.g. no finally blocks or monitor exits. So it would depend on the bytecode generated by scala.

Comment: Note that unlike `javac` which is a pretty dumb compiler (when it comes to optimizations, obviously the type inferencer, type checker, overload resolution etc. are very sophisticated), `scalac` performs sophisticated static optimizations. However, I am not sure if any of those optimizations can help with this particular problem. Note also, that there are multiple implementations of Scala, and the memory behavior is (mostly) left to the individual implementor, with the exception that the spec requires elimination of direct tail-recursion. E.g. Scala-native has or will soon have full TCO.

Comment: ECMAScript 2015 has full TCO, so, depending on the specific encoding chosen by Scala.js and whether the compiled code runs on an ECMAScript 5 or ECMAScript 2015 engine, the Scala code might enjoy full TCO as well, which in this case would mean the stack frame is re-used and the intermediate objects become unreachable immediately. Of course, the question specifically mentions the JVM. However, the J9 JVM has full TCO as well.

Comment: Many javascript engines don't actually implement TCO: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Answer (score 0):

The calls in your example are tail calls. They really shouldn't have a stack frame allocated *at all*. However, for various unfortunate reasons, the Scala Language Specification does not mandate Proper Tail Calls, and for similarly unfortunate reasons, the Scala-JVM implementation does not perform Tail Call Optimization.

However, some JVMs have TCO, e.g. the J9 JVM performs TCO, and thus there shouldn't be any additional stack frames allocated, making the intermediate objects unreachable as soon as the next tail call happens. Even JVMs that do *not* have TCO are able to perform various static (escape analysis, liveness analysis) or dynamic (escape detection, e.g. the Azul Zing JVM does this) analysis that may or may not help with this case.

There are also other implementations of Scala: Scala.js does not perform TCO, as far as I know, but it compiles to ECMAScript, and as of ECMAScript 2015, ECMAScript *does* have Proper Tail Calls, so as long as the encoding of Scala method calls ends up as ECMAScript function calls, an standards-conforming ECMAScript 2015 engine *should* eliminate Scala tail calls.

Scala-native currently does not perform TCO, but it will in the future.